# Getting properties in under test Service class by @Value returns null

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a `Spring Boot` version `2.7.0` project with different profiles for `dev` and `test` with two different properties files: `application-dev.properties` and `application-test.properties`. (I have NO default `application.properties` file.)

In under test service class I have a property that I want to load its value from `application-test.properties` file. The service class:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

    @Value("${files.root-directory}")
    private String fileDirectory;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public File createFile(CreateFileCommand command) {
        var filePath = FileUtil.getPath(fileDirectory); // <- fileDirectory is null in tests
        // ....
    }
}
```

When I run the application in `dev` profile, everything is OK. But in tests, `fileDirectory` is always null.

Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FileServiceTest {
    // ...
}
```

ApplicationTest class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class ApiApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

`application-dev.properties` file:

```
files.root-directory=${user.home}\\api\\files
```

`application-dev.properties` file:

```
files.root-directory=/home/api/var/api/files
```

**EDIT** Screenshot of file structure

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to share directory tree of your project, at least paths of properties file.

Comment: The properties files are under "src/main/resources" directory

Comment: Property file for testing should be under resources directory of test folder.

Comment: I moved application-test.properties to test resources and nothing changed. I edited the post with an screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Put your properties file under `src/test/resources`  for your (`JUnit,Integration, Contract etc`) test files. That should work!

Property files under `src/main/resources` are accessible to source files present under `src/main/` only!